# Cakephp ajax delete with j query

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

i've found this http://www.jamesfairhurst.co.uk/posts/view/ajax_delete_with_cakephp_and_jquery/ tutorial on the web, but it was for cakephp 1.3.

After making some adjustements to it , i try to run it, but something is going wrong. While the record gets deleted(as it should be), it refreshed the page. It's like Ajax and Jquery are not working. 
Below is my code

The Controller Action

```
function delete($id=null) {
    // set default class & message for setFlash
    $class = 'flash_failure';
    $msg   = 'Invalid User Id';

    // check id is valid
    if($id!=null && is_numeric($id)) {
        // get the Item
        $item = $this->User->read(null,$id);

        // check Item is valid
        if(!empty($item)) {
            $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
           // $exists=$this->User->find('count',array('conditions'=>array("User.username" => $user)));
            if($item['User']['username']==$user['username']){
                $msg = 'You cannot delete yourself!';
            }

            // try deleting the item
            else if($this->User->delete($id)) {
                $class = 'flash_success';
                $msg   = 'User was successfully deleted';
            } else {
                $msg = 'There was a problem deleting User, please try again';
            }
        }
    }

    // output JSON on AJAX request
    if(/*$this->RequestHandler->isAjax()*/$this->request->is('ajax')) {
        $this->autoRender = $this->layout = false;
        echo json_encode(array('success'=>($class=='flash_failure') ? FALSE : TRUE,'msg'=>"<p id='flashMessage' class='{$class}'>{$msg}</p>"));
        exit;
    }

    // set flash message & redirect
    $this->Session->setFlash($msg,$class,array('class'=>$class));
    $this->redirect(array('action'=>'manage'));
}
```

The View

```
    <?php //view/users/manage.ctp ?>
<h1 class="ico_mug">Users</h1>
    <?php echo 'Add User '.$this->Html->link($this->Html->image("add.jpg"), array('action' => 'register'), array('escape' => false));//print_r ($users); ?>
</br>
<table id="table">
    <tr>

        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>Last Login</th>
        <th>Options</th>

    </tr>

    <!-- Here is where we loop through our $posts array, printing out post info -->

    <?php foreach ($users as $rs): ?>
    <tr>
       <?php echo $this->Html->script('jquery'); ?>
        <td class="record">
            <?php echo $rs['User']['id']; ?>
        </td>
        <td class="record"><?php echo $rs['User']['username']; ?></td>
        <td class="record"><?php if(!$rs['User']['last_login']) {echo "Never Logged In";} else {echo $rs['User']['last_login'];} ?></td>
        <td class="record"> <?php echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("edit.jpg"), array('action' => 'edit',$rs['User']['id']), array('escape' => false));?>
            <?php
                $user = $this->Session->read('Auth.User');
                if($rs['User']['username']!=$user['username'])
                echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("cancel.jpg"), array('action' => 'delete',$rs['User']['id']), array('escape' => false),array('class'=>'confirm_delete'));?>
            <?php
            if($rs['User']['username']!=$user['username'])
            // simple HTML link with a class of 'confirm_delete'
            echo $this->Js->link('Delete',array('action'=>'delete',$rs['User']['id']),array('escape' => false),array('class'=>'confirm_delete'));
            ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

    <div class="paging">
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('<< ' . __('previous'), array(), null, array('class'=>'disabled'));?>
        |  <?php echo $this->Paginator->numbers();?>
        |  <?php echo $this->Paginator->next(__('next') . ' >>', array(), null, array('class' => 'disabled'));?>
    </div>

</table>
    <div id='ajax_loader'></div>
```

The Jquery

```
// on dom ready
$(document).ready(function(){
// class exists
if($('.confirm_delete').length) {
        // add click handler
    $('.confirm_delete').click(function(){
        // ask for confirmation
        var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');

        // show loading image
        $('.ajax_loader').show();
        $('#flashMessage').fadeOut();

        // get parent row
        var row = $(this).parents('tr');

        // do ajax request
        if(result) {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:$(this).attr('href'),
                data:"ajax=1",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(response){
                    // hide loading image
                    $('.ajax_loader').hide();

                    // hide table row on success
                    if(response.success == true) {
                        row.fadeOut();
                    }

                    // show respsonse message
                    if( response.msg ) {
                        $('#ajax_msg').html( response.msg ).show();
                    } else {
                        $('#ajax_msg').html( "<p id='flashMessage' class='flash_bad'>An unexpected error has occured, please refresh and try again</p>" ).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    return false;
    });
}
});
```

Please take in mind that i'm very new to all this Jquery and Ajax thing, as well as in cakephp.

What is causing that behaviour ? (also if i try to remove the redire from the controller, i get a message that "view delete was not found" )

Answer (score 1):

First of all check cookbook for [HtmlHelper::link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3alink) and [JsHelper::link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/js.html#JsHelper%3a%3alink). Not sure what version of cake you have, so just switch to the right one. 
The thing is - none of your `Delete` links has class `confirm_delete` (use firebug or some debugging tool) - so the link gets clicked but the javascript is never executed, that's why you get redirected.
In your case it would be:

```
echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('cancel.png'), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'delete', $rs['User']['id']), array('escape'=>false, 'class'=>'confirm_delete') );
```

and

```
echo $this->Js->link('Delete', array('controller' => 'users', 'action'=>'delete', $rs['User']['id']), array('escape' => false, 'class'=>'confirm_delete'));
```

Then I see `$('.ajax_loader').hide();` but in your view is element with `id="ajax_loader"`, so the selector should be `$('#ajax_loader').hide();`
Same with `$('#ajax_msg').html(`, double check you have that element on page with the `id="ajax_msg"`
Hope it helps you further;)

Comment: I've changed the delete link to echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image('cancel.png',
                array("alt" => "Delete","class"=>"confirm_delete")
                ),
                array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'delete', $rs['User']['id']),
                array('escape'=>false, 'confirm' => 'Are You sure you want to Delete?',"class"=>"confirm_delete")
                ); 
but still it doesnt seem to work. also i added the correct class for the divs, but yet nothing happens

Comment: i already did that, but it didnt work. If i remove from the controller the line `$this->redirect(array('action'=>'manage'));`  i just get an error message that a view for the action delete is not found! tha's why i ask again, Is there something wrong with the Jquery/Ajax , and how can i do ajax without getting that error in cake 2.0 ?

Comment: If you have any javascript error, you will follow the link's URL via ordinary GET request, so the line `if($this->request->is('ajax'))` is always FALSE and you proceed to the lines below. Without the redirect, cake implements autoRender feature and expects to render the corresponding view, delete.ctp, which you don't have, ok? When I try your code it works, so I guess you are missing the `<div id="ajax_msg">` or have some other error. Best is to provide test URL so I can check exactly what's wrong...

Comment: Attention guys, this code is vulnerable to Cross-site request forgery,
it would be better if you create a Form (include the Security-Component!) and send it via ajax.

In the delete-method instead of:

`public function delete($id)
{.....

then do this:

public function delete()
{
  $id = $this->data['User']['id'];
....`

Doing it this way, when  included the security-component a hidden token gets generated wich protects your action from csrf.

Cheers